# Alter existing chain spec without mutating genesis hash

Tags: chainspec, genesis, test-network

What contents of a non-raw chain spec can be added or altered without mutating the derived genesis hash? More specifically, does changing a pallet's genesis configuration in the spec lead to a different genesis hash?

**Context**: Say a test-network halts and requires `codeSubstitutes` addition in the chain spec. However, upon restarting with the altered spec, the client throws with

```
Error: Input("\"Error parsing embedded file: unknown field `interestAccrual`, expected one of `system`, `parachainSystem`, `parachainInfo`, `balances`, `collatorSelection`, `session`, `aura`, `auraExt`, `council`, `elections`, `democracy`, `vesting`, `treasury`, `fees`, `collatorAllowlist`, `blockRewardsBase`, `blockRewards`, `liquidityRewardsBase`, `polkadotXcm`, `ormlTokens`, `ormlAssetRegistry`, `evm`, `evmChainId`, `baseFee`, `ethereum` at line 193 column 24\"")
```

because some pallets' genesis configurations have changed in between the testnet's genesis and now such that the `GenesisBuild` storage behaves differently. This problem can be solved by updating/removing the erroneous pallets' configurations/storages in the spec. However, that does not appear to be the correct approach as I fear it will lead to a different genesis hash.

Shouldn't the `genesis.runtime.system.code` be used automatically to not run into the stated compiler error?

Answer (score 1):

The genesis hash is the hash of the genesis storage. So changing a pallet's genesis configuration (genesis storage) will indeed result in a different genesis hash.

When launching a node to your network with `codeSubstitutes` it needs the same genesis state as how the network was initially launched. In other words, don't modify the chainspec aside from including a new validation function in `codeSubstitutes`.

Comment: Thanks! But how to resolve the above client error message above then? It appears to me that the client version from the original genesis spec needs to be run with the `codeSubstitutes` addition? I would have thought even newer clients would still execute the wasm from `genesis.runtime.system.code`. However that is not the case.

Comment: You simply take the original chainspec that you used to at launch and add the `codesubstitutes`. Don't try to build it again from scratch.

Comment: That part is clear to me. But when you want to use this chain spec with a newer client version, the client can throw the above error message if any pallet's `GenesisBuild` has changed. Say the chain launched 2021 and two years later you need to add `codeSubstitutes`. The current client version won't run with the spec. So what can you do apart from building (i.e. docker image) a client based on 2021 with the altered chain spec?

Comment: May be related, see comments here: https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/9949/newer-nodes-unable-to-execute-genesis-chainspec-unknown-field-phantom