# Newer nodes unable to execute genesis chainspec, "unknown field `phantom`"

Tags: substrate-node, validator, chainspec, genesis

We've been running a testnet and have executed a number of runtime upgrades. We've also upgraded the node across a variety of changes. New validators are trying to join the network and yet they cannot now run our genesis chainspec.

The network was probably launched around `polkadot-v0.9.39` changes.

#### Error

`Error: Service(Other("Error parsing spec file: unknown field` phantom`, there are no fields at line 175 column 17"))`

What's the proper way to debug this and how can we onboard new nodes to our network? It seems we're stuck.

Comment: This sounds like you are using the JSON chain spec, not the raw chain spec which should be forever compatible.

Comment: Yea I suspected this, yet running the raw generation on the later node also fails. We will attempt to resolve going back to the OG node.

Comment: Raw generation of an old JSON on new nodes are not guaranteed to work. There could be breaking changes to the JSON format. This is why the raw chain spec exists.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed by generating raw chainspec using original node the JSON was created with. Generating raw spec with a newer node doesn't work (and is obviously not guaranteed to work).